# Using IS NULL with JPQL?

Tags: eclipse, jpa, jpql

I have 2 Entity, Aluno and Matricula. I want return all Aluno without Matricula. To do this, I'm trying use IS NULL of JPQL but still could not do this work.

How can I do this ?

I'm trying this.

```
@Entity
public class Aluno{
   @Id @GenerateValue
   private Long id;

   @OneToOne
   private Matricula matricula
}


@Entity
public class Matricula{
  @Id @GenerateValue
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne
  private Aluno aluno;
}

//
public List<Aluno> getAlunosWithoutMatricula(){
    String jpql = "SELECT a FROM Aluno a JOIN a.matricula mat WHERE mat IS NULL";
        TypedQuery<Aluno> query = em.createQuery(jpql, Aluno.class);
        return query.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: your problem is in use join. when you use join this means you use inner join. for solve this problem you can use left join instead of join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem

here.

```
public List<Aluno> getAlunosWithoutMatricula(){
    String jpql = "SELECT a FROM Aluno a WHERE (a.matricula IS NULL)";
        TypedQuery<Aluno> query = em.createQuery(jpql, Aluno.class);
        return query.getResultList();
}
```